# What are the new achievements in Legend of Dead Kel?

Tags: achievements, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

The new Kingdoms of Amalur DLC says it has five new achievements. What are they, and how do I get them?

Comment: Any answer you get will most likely be speculation because I don't think any information has been released.

Comment: Oh ... I thought this was out, guess that's why I can't find out

Answer (score 1):

- Message in a Bottle (25 points)   Locate all eight message bottles in Gallows End.
- Keep on Rising      (50 points)   Fully restore Gravehal Keep.
- Exterminator        (25 points)   Kill 50 Scavs.

Plus 2 Secret Achievements (via [Xbox360Achievements.org](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/achievements/)):

> Give Her a Hand (25 points, Found Aubrey Gilcrest's severed hand), and Manic Pixie Dream Elf (25 points, Wooed Rast Brattlgan).

If you're having a hard time getting them, there appears to be an XBox360 bug right now that's not allowing them to unlock, it should resolve itself when Microsoft updates the achievement list.